# Geolocation not available on iPhone using Safari/Chrome with react web app

Tags: reactjs, iphone, typescript, geolocation

I have a react web app which looks to get the current logged in users geolocation. Works fine on desktop(and Android) but when published and ran on iPhone the location is not being recorded. Other websites on iPhone can ask for location permissions fine so I'm just assuming its something else that I need to do in my code to make it work.

I'm using the following code to determine if geolocation is available and then recording the location:

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        const loc = {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude.toString(),
            longitude: position.coords.longitude.toString()
        };
    // Send loc to service 
}
```

This works fine on desktop and on Android phones but not on iPhone.

Is there something else I need to do instead of this?

Comment: using https or http?

Comment: Using https. I initially thought that would be the problem but no.